# How can I create degree symbol through handlebar.js?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Sorry, this might be a very simple question, but I couldn't find the answer so please help me.

My `html` guy is given a `handlebar` template for showing the temperature unit value(°C,°F) just like in the following way.

```
<script id="unlogged-navTpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 <h3>{{unitText}}</h3>
</script>
```

I templates with the following way.

```
 var result=Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("unlogged-navTpl"));     
 result({unitText:&deg;C'})
```

It's working fine,the thing was I can't able see value after compile(°C ).It showing `&deg;C`

How can I fix this.

Please can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either include the literal character or use an [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings) in the JavaScript string:

```
result({ unitText: '\u00B0C' });
```

But, the rendering of HTML entities won't work as expected with `{{...}}` placeholders as they will treat the values as text and re-encode any `&` as a special character, resulting in:

```
<h3>&amp;deg;C</h3>
```

[`{{{...}}}`](http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping) placeholders (with 3 braces on each side) will skip the encoding, allowing for rendering "*raw*" HTML values.

Comment: Interesting. Any idea why he would be seeing "&deg;C" as he reports?

Comment: @Sneagan Because the `&` is being encoded again. So, `&amp;deg;C` rather than being left as `&deg;C`.

Comment: D'oh! Right. Removed my answer.